# What precisely is the interpretation of distance correlation?

Tags: correlation, distance-covariance

The key feature of [distance correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) is that if it is $0$ then two variables are independent. If the pearson correlation is zero, however, this does not imply independence. How would one interpret distance correlation?

Comment: I believe some help is provided in the [Wikipedia article on "energy distance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_distance).